# How to classify the the critical points of this nonlinear system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Consider the nonlinear system:
\begin{align}
 \dot x &= -x - \frac{y}{\log \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \\
 \dot y &= -y + \frac{x}{\log \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
\end{align}
a) Show that the origin is a stable node for linearized system:

Attempt at the solution:

The Jacobian is 
$$ J(x, y) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{x y}{(x^2 + y^2) \log^2{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}} - 1 & \frac{y^2}{(x^2 + y^2) \log^2{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}- \frac{1}{\log\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \\
\frac{1}{\log\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} - \frac{x^2}{(x^2 + y^2) \log^2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} &  -\frac{x y}{(x^2 + y^2) \log^2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} - 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
As we approach $(0, 0)$ it appears that $J$ approaches 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
 0  & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
if this is true then it shows $(0, 0)$ is a stable node. However, I'm unsure how to show this rigorously.

b) Show that the origin of the nonlinear system is not a stable node but rather a stable spiral.

Attempt at the solution:
I am unsure how to proceed for this part.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: (b) Compute $\dot r$ and $\dot\theta$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$.